# Get object script in SQL Server via T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, scripting

I need to get the *creation script* of an object in a SQL Server database. I need the exact same script that was used to create it. Like when you use SSMS to alter a view you already defined, and then the script is there, just the way you've defined it earlier.

I need to do this in T-SQL. Where does SQL Server store the scripts related to the database objects? I can't find the related view in system catalog views.

What I'm trying to find is something like:

```
select creation_script -- I know this column doesn't exist
from sys.objects
where name = 'CustomersView'
```

Comment: Why the exact same script? What version of SQL server?

Comment: If you're interested in views and procedures, you could use sp_helptext

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, by exact, I don't mean even capitalization. I just want all the structures to be the same. All `with` options, all `cascades` on foreign keys, etc.

Comment: Ah. That kind of script isn't stored anywhere. You'd have to piece it together yourself from all the different sys tables

Comment: @JamesZ, that's what I'm searching for, but for all objects. Right now, I'm stuck in foreign keys. Is there anything similar to `sp_helptext` for other objects too?

Comment: For the rest I think you'll have to parse them together from the DMVs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not feasible in T-SQL. Not all object have a definition stored and you would have to reverse engineer CREATE scripts for basic things like tables and indexes.

Rather than reinvent the wheel (in T-SQL), do the proper thing and reuse the component dedicated for this purpose the SMO [`Scripter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter.aspx) class. Is already available, works, is up to date with all the latest SQL Server objects, is free to redistribute along with SMO. Simply move your scripting logic out of T-SQL.

Comment: What he said.  Here's a good article on doing it via Powershell: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/

Answer (score 6):

While not disputing that the most comprehensive method is to use SMO as Remus suggested in his [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/95274/30859), this question does request to get the info via T-SQL and that info does exist for some objects. Just keep in mind that this info:

- covers a small set of object types
- does not include any `GRANT` / `DENY` statements. But you can get that info from `sys.database_permissions` and `sys.database_principals`.
- does not include any `IF EXISTS DROP` logic
- does not include the session settings of `ANSI_NULLS` and `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER`. Those you get from `sys.sql_modules` via the `[uses_ansi_nulls]` and `[uses_quoted_identifier]` fields.
- *might* not include the Schema Name. If the Schema Name was not explicitly stated in the CREATE (or ALTER) statement, then the Schema Name will not be a part of the definition. The Schema will have been whatever the default Schema was for the User that created the object, at the time of creation. If the Schema Name is not included in the definition and cannot be assumed to be something like `dbo`, then it will have to be discovered via `OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id])`

---

**Object Catalog Views**

The [sys.sql_modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) Catalog View has the full `CREATE...` statement for the following objects (anything encrypted will return `NULL` for the `[definition]`):

- SQL Stored Procedure
- Replication-filter-procedure
- View
- SQL DML trigger
- SQL Database-level DDL trigger
- SQL scalar function
- SQL inline table-valued function
- SQL table-valued-function
- Rule (old-style, stand-alone)
- Default (stand-alone, NOT constraint)

```sql
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) AS [SchemaName],
       OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) AS [ObjectName],
       *
FROM   sys.sql_modules;
```

The [sys.check_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187388.aspx) and [sys.default_constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173758.aspx) Catalog Views will return the logic portion of their respective constraints as the `[definition]`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sys.check_constraints;

SELECT *
FROM   sys.default_constraints;
```

**Metadata Function**

The [OBJECT_DEFINITION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) function will return the same data that is in the `[definition]` field of the three previously mentioned Catalog Views, based on the specified `[object_id]`:

```sql
SELECT so.name,
       so.[type],
       so.type_desc,
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(so.[object_id]) AS [Definiton]
FROM   sys.objects so
WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(so.[object_id]) IS NOT NULL;
```

---

**Other Objects**

Here are some resources for finding the meta-data related to all object types:

- [Object Catalog Views](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx)
- [Metadata Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187812.aspx)
- [Querying the SQL Server System Catalog FAQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use Profiler for a moment (or Extended Events or a server-side trace), and then produce some of the scripts you want via Management Studio. Make sure you've got the scripting options you want turned on - you may prefer to use Tasks | Generate Scripts at the database level.

Anyway, the point being that you can have a look at what queries run, and get a feel for what's involved.

Another option is to start with a fresh database, and use DDL triggers to store everything that gets run to create or alter objects. Then you have the actual scripts used and you have a repository you can easily hook into when required, with the exact queries that were used at the time.

Comment: +1. Your second option (DDL triggers) is very interesting. Can you guide me more in that? How about updates? How to get the latest definition of objects? How to remove older definitions?

Comment: If you store every CREATE, ALTER, DROP, then you will have the full history, including the latest versions. See more at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/

Comment: ObOtherWayToDoIT.  I've been using Event Notifications for the past couple years with great success.  (So great I now present on it at SQLSatrudays). Here's my current presentation, slide deck, demos, code repository and all.  https://www.sqlsaturday.com/viewsession.aspx?sat=362&sessionid=25219

Comment: Yup, Event Notifications do the trick too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Several years back I was able to generate object scripts on-the-fly using Distributed Management Objects and [sp_OACreate](http://www.mssqlcity.com/articles/general/oleautsp.htm).  If your SQL instance is sufficiently old you will be able to use these.  It was surprisingly easy and operationally reliable.

Newer versions of SQL Server have SMO which can be called from .Net.

Comment: 1) The OLE automation procs (i.e. `sp_OA*`) have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Even if they do technically still work, and even if someone does happen to be on a "sufficiently old" version of SQL Server, it is generally a bad idea to create new functionality for anything other than a one-time need via this method as it is very time-limited. 2) SMO very much _can't_ be called via SQLCLR. You did not read the comments below that answer that you linked to (i.e. the accepted answer is specifically wrong). I have just added an answer to that S.O. question clarifying the issue.